# How can I get the service bus topic from configuration when using IAsyncCollector?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an Azure Function that publishes some messages to the service bus, declared like this:

```cs
[FunctionName(FunctionNames.PublishMessages)]
public async Task PublishMessages(
    [ActivityTrigger] IEnumerable<Foo> messages,
    [ServiceBus("TopicName", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<string> collector,
    ILogger log)
{
    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        await collector.AddAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(message));
    }

    await collector.FlushAsync();
}
```

The output binding for the service bus takes the name of the topic and the name of the configuration key whose value contains the connection string.

Instead of hard-coding the topic in the method signature I'd like to get it from the function's configuration, in the same way I get the connection string.  Is this possible?  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by [referencing it using `%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-expressions---app-settings). So

```
[ServiceBus("%TopicNameSetting%", Connection = ...
```

and create an app setting with the key `TopicNameSetting`